# Getting lots of Error Debug Information emails

Tags: debug

I'm getting a lot of emails from Magento with content that looks like this:

```
URL: http://www.mydomain.com/my-product-slug/reviews/+Result:+chosen+nickname+%22egegsduy01%22;+success+%28from+first+page%29;
IP Address: 173.208.194.13
First Name: sybjfgsu43
Last Name: wbmtblmp54CA
E-mail Address: totttiayao@sina.com
Telephone: 123456
Comment: &lt;a href=http://www.hodescenter.com/mk/&gt;&lt;b&gt;michael kors outlet online&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/a&gt; &lt;a href=http://www.razorlocator.com/michaelkors/&gt;&lt;b&gt;cheap michael kors purses&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/a&gt; &lt;a href=http://www.hodescenter.com/mk/&gt;&lt;b&gt;cheap michael kors purses&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/a&gt; &lt;a href=http://www.evanstour.com/mk/&gt;&lt;b&gt;michael kors outlet online&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/a&gt; &lt;a href=http://www.razorlocator.com/michaelkors/&gt;&lt;b&gt;michael kors purses&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/a&gt; &lt;a href=http://www.outbackphoto.org/cheapjerseys/?q=cheap-jerseys.html&gt;&lt;b&gt;cheap nfl authentic jerseys&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/a&gt; &lt;a href=http://www.stormchasehomepage.com/jerseys/?q=cheap-nfl-jerseys.html&gt;&lt;b&gt;cheap nfl authentic jerseys&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/a&gt; On its website, Palcohol says aspect plans to learn more about provide six varieties about dust alcohol, including vodka,rum and four cocktails  &lt;a href=http://www.outbackphoto.org/cheapjerseys/?q=nike-nfl-jerseys.html&gt;&lt;b&gt;cheap nfl nike jerseys&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/a&gt; &lt;a href=http://www.evanstour.com/mk/&gt;&lt;b&gt;michael kors purses&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/a&gt; &lt;a href=http://www.stormchasehomepage.com/jerseys/?q=cheap-nfl-jerseys.html&gt;&lt;b&gt;cheap nfl jerseys free shipping&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/a&gt;  &lt;a href=http://www.hodescenter.com/mk/&gt;&lt;b&gt;michael kors handbags&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/a&gt; &lt;a href=http://www.evanstour.com/mk/&gt;&lt;b&gt;michael kors purses&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/a&gt; Dehqan said blankets and tents had seen and heard and about 400 it is certainly plausible from nearby villages had gathered to learn more about facilitate so that you have going to be the rescue effort  &lt;a href=http://www.razorlocator.com/michaelkors/&gt;&lt;b&gt;cheap michael kors&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/a&gt; &lt;a href=http://www.evanstour.com/mk/&gt;&lt;b&gt;cheap
```

Where mydomain.com/my-product-slug is fictitious.

Is there anything that I can do to prevent this from happening? It looks like unsuccessful spam posts.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Captcha on reviews and contact us page, even on third party module (if you are using any) which generates emails. like faqs etc